# Programatically enable iOS keyboard on orientation change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I'm building a website with responsive design that goes between mobile and desktop view if the viewport is big/small enough.  Because of this, I have two search bars (mobile and desktop).  On an iPad, I want to be able to rotate the screen while focusing on one search bar, and the other is focused on automatically, including a keyboard.

Here's what I have going in my script for right now:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
        $('input').css('cursor', 'pointer');

        if($('.search-input-mobile').css('display') != 'none' && $('.search-input').css('display') == 'none' && $('input:focus').length > 0 && Math.abs(window.orientation) != 90) {
            $('.search-input-mobile').trigger('click');
        } else if(Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90 && $('input:focus').length > 0 ) {
                $('.search-input').trigger('click');
        } else if($('input:focus').length > 0 ) {
            $('.search-input-mobile').trigger('click');
        }
    };

    $('.search-input').click(function(e){
        alert('got desktop');
        document.activeElement.blur();
        $('.search-input-mobile').blur();
        var temp = $('.search-input-mobile').val();
        $('.search-input').val('');
        $('.search-input').val(temp);
        $('.search-input').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.search-input-mobile').click(function(e){
        alert('got mobile');
        document.activeElement.blur();
        var temp = $('.search-input').val();
        if (temp != '') {
            $('.search-input-mobile').val('');
            $('.search-input-mobile').val(temp);
        }
        $('.search-input-mobile').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I've tried pretty much everything I can find on SO to no avail.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  As a side note, I would like to avoid extra libraries if at all possible.